# Copy tmux selection to windows clipboard in cygwin/minTTY

Tags: cygwin, tmux, clipboard, mintty

I use tmux in my cygwin-minTTY in windows, with mouse-support.

When I select a text in the terminal, it gets copied to the tmux buffer. But I want to have it in the Windows clipboard!

I can run `tmux save-buffer - > /dev/clipboard` manually and I can make an alias of it, but that always is *typing* and I want to spare that. Can I somehow bind it to the mouse-selecting mechanism, in addition to copying to the buffer of course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line into `.tmux.conf`:

`bind -n C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | /mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe" \; display-message "Tmux clipboard copied to Windows clipboard"`

Binds `Ctrl+y` to copy tmux buffer into windows clipboard via clipboard executable `clip.exe` (don't forget to check the path to the `clip.exe`).

On status bar you should see a message *"Tmux clipboard copied to Windows clipboard"*

Comment: That is great! But I guess there is no way to add this to the selection process?

Comment: @Bowi I presume you have `set-window-option -g mode-mouse on`.  If you try pressing `option` (normally `alt`) before and during the selection process it should go to the system clipboard.

Comment: I only have `set -g mouse on`, with that, it doesn't work. When I replace it with your line, it says *invalid option: mode-mouse* on start.

Comment: @Bowi ah, yes you are right.  That is the "new" style option.  Your option is correct for the newest tmux, did you try it with the alt press?

Comment: Yes, I did -- when I press *Alt* before mousedown, the selection does not start at all, when I press it while selection is in progress, the selection freezes. Or do I have another *option* without knowing?

Comment: @Bowi then try, `Shift` or `Ctrl`.

Comment: No success. :-( What is that *option* after all? I have a pretty standard tmux, when I want to create another window, I type `Ctrl + b`, `c`.

Comment: @Bowi in tmux you have a modifiers, and on terminal you have options.  The terminal should enable you to pass the copied text if the modifier is pressed, but I don't know your configuration, to outer system as I have shown via the `ctrl+y` shortcut.  The mouse I did not try so that is guessing.  You could try it out with the `tmux-yank` plugin if that would help `https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank`, if nothing helps.

Comment: Okay, I will try the yank. But for now, the method in your answer is enough. :-)

Comment: @Bowi thank you and you are welcome :)